# docker image build command fails with "(Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"

Tags: 16.04, proxy

I am new to docker and Ubuntu 16.04 OS as well. My configuration is as follows :

Ubuntu:

```
$lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Release:    16.04

Codename:   xenial
```

Docker :

```
$ docker info

Containers: 2

 Running: 0

 Paused: 0

 Stopped: 2

Images: 5

Server Version: 18.09.0

Storage Driver: overlay2

 Backing Filesystem: extfs

 Supports d_type: true

 Native Overlay Diff: true

Logging Driver: json-file

Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs

Plugins:

 Volume: local

 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay

 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk 
syslog

Swarm: inactive

Runtimes: runc

Default Runtime: runc

Init Binary: docker-init

containerd version: c4446665cb9c30056f4998ed953e6d4ff22c7c39

runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871

init version: fec3683

Security Options:

 apparmor

 seccomp

  Profile: default

Kernel Version: 4.15.0-42-generic

Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

OSType: linux

Architecture: x86_64

CPUs: 4

Total Memory: 15.4GiB

Name: smarthi-ORADEV

ID: 3OIT:CLN4:HNUU:W4SG:Z6OZ:NRRV:WSSN:E7PO:A2ZZ:XGYI:CXUZ:VBUD

Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker

Debug Mode (client): false

Debug Mode (server): false

Username: bluesangig

Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/

Labels:

Experimental: false

Insecure Registries:

 127.0.0.0/8

Live Restore Enabled: false

Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

I am connect to office VPN network and all my accesses to office and internet are working fine with my Network proxy configuration done in my laptop.

Even `docker container run` commands are also working fine.

But when I try to do `docker image build` using a docker file whose content is:

FROM busybox
RUN echo "building simple docker image"
CMD [echo, "hello container"]

I am getting below error message:

```
$ docker image build -t testimg .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM busybox
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I had searched a bit and found that we may need to set the proxy in the `~/.docker/config.json` file, and I had added the proxy entries as mentioned in the [issue](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/507)

Even after adding the entries as suggested in the above issue, I still face the same issue.

I am little clueless now on how to solve this issue with docker image build. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

After a much trail and error and lot of googling... finally I was able to make docker work behind my office VPN.

And for the benefit of people who might be facing issue similar to mine, below are the steps I performed to resolve the issue:

Three different places where I had modified the proxy value and that got the issue fixed.

1. **`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`** Check if this file exists in your setup, and if it does not create this file and perform below steps:

   - Open the file and add below statements in it and save:

     ```
     [Service]
     Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyHost:proxyPort"
     Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxyHost:proxyPort"
     Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1"
     ```
   - Flush the above changes by running below command:

     ```
     sudo systemctl daemon-reload
     ```
   - Verify that the above changes have been taken affect by running the command below. This should print the Environment variable value:

     ```
     sudo system ctl show --property Environment docker
     ```
   - Once you successfully verify that the variable is set, restart the docker service by running below command:

     ```
     sudo systemctl restart docker
     ```
2. **`~/.docker/config.json`**: Add the json property shown below to the existing properties in the file.

   ```
       "proxies": {
         "defaults": {
           "httpProxy":"http://proxyHost:proxyPort",
           "httpsProxy":"http://proxyHost:proxyPort"
         }
       }
   ```
3. **`/etc/default/docker`** : Open or create this file with this content:

   ```
   export http_proxy='http://proxyHost:proxyPort'
   export https_proxy='http://proxyHost:proxyPort'
   ```

Once I had all the above changes done, I rebooted my setup and then docker image pull and other docker commands started working without issues.

Note: All the above changes may not be required but for me above changes made sure that docker works after I connect to my VPN.

Comment: On Linux I had to use lower case names for the proxy to work. So in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf I had to use "Environment=http_proxy=http...", with lower case and no quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In the file `/etc/default/docker`, add:

```
export http_proxy='http://<host>:<port>'
export https_proxy='http://<host>:<port>'
```

Restart Docker

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I donot see /etc/default/docker file in my system. I see this issue everytime I reboot my machine. And one of my friends has suggested to to add "Acquire::http::proxy "<proxyHost>:<proxyPort>/"; in /etc/apt/apt.conf file... If I do that I see that things started working. But today even that solution is not working... Any suggestions on how to make the network stable on my system? Please help

Comment: I had even tried adding the above file with the export statmements in it:
$ cat /etc/default/docker 
export http_proxy='http://www-proxy.us.oracle.com:80/'
export https_proxy='http://www-proxy.us.oracle.com:80/'

Still I see the same issue occurring:
$ docker container run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.

Any further help with this regards?